# Call Ipython Notebook interact with variable number of parameters

Tags: python, widget, ipython, jupyter-notebook, interactive

There is a nice example of using interactive widgets to adjust the coefficients of a polynomial on a plot:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from IPython.html.widgets import interact, interactive, fixed
from IPython.html import widgets
def f(a, b, c, d, **kwargs):
    x=np.linspace(-10, 10, 20)
    y = a*(x**3) + b*(x**2) + c*x + d 
    title="$f(x) = (%s)x^{3} + (%s)x^{2} + (%s)x + (%s)$" % (a,b,c,d) 
    plt_arrays(x,y, title=title, **kwargs)
#This function plot x, y and adds a title
def plt_arrays(x, y, title="", color="red", linestyle="dashed", linewidth=2):
    fig = plt.figure()
    axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
    axes.plot(x,y, color=color, linestyle=linestyle, linewidth=linewidth)
    axes.set_title(title)
    axes.grid()
    plt.show()
i = interact(f,
             a=(-10.,10),
             b=(-10.,10),
             c=(-10.,10),
             d=(-10.,10),
             color = ["red", "blue", "green"],
             linestyle=["solid", "dashed"],
             linewidth=(1,5)
             )
```

That can be found here: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/twistedhardware/mltutorial/blob/master/notebooks/IPython-Tutorial/6%20-%20IPython%20Widgets.ipynb

My question is how can one add the flexibility to make this work if you didn't know the order of the polynomial in advance?  Say the user wanted to call this with a seventh order polynomial and so seven sliders would appear for the coefficients a-g.  Or for a third order polynomial so only three sliders would appear for coefficients a-c.  I can't figure out how to call interact without knowing the number of arguments in advance.